# How can I verify if the email belongs to an account that has a password?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a lot of kind of users, some users is log up with google account, others with google account and password, i only want to send the reset mail `sendPasswordResetEmail` if the email belong to user have a password, not to every kind of account, this each user have to do when the user is not login.

i used this function `sendPasswordResetEmail` but that function sent mail to everybody, i had a google account without password, that is wrong to me

Comment: you have to use a cloud function to get all the users and then check if the userType is `password` and then send email to only who are authenticated with email and password,

Comment: @sairaj but i am using firebase client by reactjs

Comment: you basically want to send email to all the users who are authenticated with email and password right

Comment: You don't need Cloud functions to get providers of currently logged in user.

Comment: ya but he wants to send to all users that is probably a admin action

Comment: @sairaj the reset passwrod is for a user, not for everybody

Comment: the the answer by @Dharmaraj is the right one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check user's auth providers and check if that includes Email-Password:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user !== null) {
  if (user.providerData.find(p => p.providerId === "password")) {
    // user had email-password account
    // send email
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your example check if the email has a password?

Comment: i will try your answer i will tell you if it work

Comment: but the user is not login, your example works when an user is login

Comment: @brucelee then there's no way to do so using client SDK. You would have to use Admin SDK with Cloud Functions or a server.

Comment: how can i do this since AdminSDK?